# Как сравнить 4 списка со словарями между собой? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 4 списка со словарями:

```
a = [{key1 : value_a1}, {key2 : value_a2}]
b = [{key1 : value_b1}, {key2 : value_b2}]
c = [{key1 : value_c1}, {key2 : value_c2}]
d = [{key1 : value_d1}, {key2 : value_d2}]
```

Нужно сравнить значения, у которых одинаковые ключи, каждого словаря между собой и если они различаются, вывести эти словари и из каких они списков

Comment: И что вы уже попробовали сделать?

Comment: У меня получилось неработающее чудо с кучей вложенных циклов

Comment: 1 - нужно показывать свои попытки решить задачу. 2 - все списки имеют одинаковый набор словарей с одинаковыми ключами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мое решение "в лоб", насколько я понял условие. Код крайне кривой, но при желании не составит труда довести до ума

```py
list_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


def check_by_key(key, val):
    _cur_list = 0

    for _i in a, b, c, d:
        for _j in _i:
            for _k in _j.keys():
                if key == _k and (_j[_k] != val):
                    yield _j, list_names[_cur_list]

        _cur_list += 1


for i in a, b, c, d:
    cur_list = 0

    for j in i:
        for k in j.items():
            for ans in check_by_key(*k):
                cur_list_name = list_names[cur_list]
                print(f"{j} from list {cur_list_name}: {ans[0]} from list {ans[1]}")
    cur_list += 1
```